# Vue 3 Composable console error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isError')

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have this Vue 3 / TypeScript Composable that uploads an image to Firebase storage:

```TypeScript
interface ImageUpload {
  uploadTask?: UploadTask;
  downloadURL?: string;
  progress?: number;
  error?: Error;
  isCanceled: boolean;
  isRunning: boolean;
  isPaused: boolean;
  isSuccess: boolean;
  isError: boolean;
}

export const useImageUpload = (file: File) => {
  const imageUpload = ref<ImageUpload>({
    uploadTask: undefined,
    downloadURL: undefined,
    progress: undefined,
    error: undefined,
    isRunning: true,
    isCanceled: false,
    isPaused: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isError: false,
  });

  // Create the file metadata
  const metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  };

  // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
  const filePath = `user_images/${user.uid}/${file.name + '_' + uid()}`;
  const storageReference = storageRef(store, filePath);
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageReference, file, metadata);

  //Put the task into the ref
  imageUpload.value.uploadTask = uploadTask;

  // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
  const unsubscribe = uploadTask.on(
    'state_changed',
    (snapshot) => {
      // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
      const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      imageUpload.value.progress = progress;
      console.log(`Upload is ${progress}% done`);
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case 'canceled':
          imageUpload.value.isCanceled = true;
          imageUpload.value.isRunning = false;
          console.log('Upload is canceled');
          break;
        case 'paused':
          imageUpload.value.isPaused = true;
          imageUpload.value.isRunning = false;
          console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case 'running':
          imageUpload.value.isPaused = false;
          imageUpload.value.isRunning = true;
          console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      // Upload error
      imageUpload.value.isError = true;
      imageUpload.value.isRunning = false;
      imageUpload.value.error = error;
      console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
      // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
        .then((downloadURL) => {
          imageUpload.value.downloadURL = downloadURL;
          imageUpload.value.isSuccess = true;
          imageUpload.value.isRunning = false;
          console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // getDownloadURL error
          imageUpload.value.isError = true;
          imageUpload.value.isRunning = false;
          if (error instanceof Error) {
            imageUpload.value.error = error;
          }
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  );
  // Unsub the listener when the composable is not in use
  watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
    onInvalidate(() => {
      unsubscribe();
    });
  });

  return imageUpload;
};
```

And I am using it in a Vue component like this:

```Vue
<template>
  <div>
    <q-img :src="picUrl" />
    <q-file
      ref="picFileRef"
      v-model="picFile"
      style="display: none"
      @update:model-value="handlePicUpdate"
    />
    <div v-if="imageUpload.isError">
      {{ imageUpload.error?.message }}
    </div>
    <div v-if="imageUpload.isRunning">Loading...</div>
    <q-btn type="button" label="Upload Image" @click="handleUploadClick" />
    <q-btn type="button" label="Pause" @click="handlePauseClick" />
    <q-btn type="button" label="Resume" @click="handleResumeClick" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';
import { useImageUpload } from 'src/composables/storage';
import { QFile } from 'quasar';
import { UploadTask } from 'firebase/storage';

const picFile = ref<File>();
const picUrl = ref<string>();
const picFileRef = ref() as Ref<QFile>;

interface ImageUpload {
  uploadTask?: UploadTask;
  downloadURL?: string;
  progress?: number;
  error?: Error;
  isCanceled: boolean;
  isRunning: boolean;
  isPaused: boolean;
  isSuccess: boolean;
  isError: boolean;
}

let imageUpload: Ref<ImageUpload>; // Had to declare this at the top level so I could access it's properties in the template and in other functions

const handleUploadClick = () => {
  picFileRef.value.pickFiles();
};
const handlePicUpdate = () => {
  if (picFile.value) {
    imageUpload = useImageUpload(picFile.value);
    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log('progress', imageUpload.value.progress);
      console.log('isRunning', imageUpload.value.isRunning);
      console.log('isPaused', imageUpload.value.isPaused);
      if (imageUpload.value.downloadURL) {
        picUrl.value = imageUpload.value.downloadURL;
      }
    });
  }
};
const handlePauseClick = () => {
  imageUpload.value.uploadTask?.pause();
};
const handleResumeClick = () => {
  imageUpload.value.uploadTask?.resume();
};
</script>
```

I have no errors in my IDE (Visual Studio Code) but when I run it I get this console error, plus 3 others that look very similar:

```
WebsitePage.vue?bfce:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isError')
    at Proxy.render (WebsitePage.vue?bfce:21:1)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?9e79:893:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?9e79:5030:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?0a2b:167:1)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?9e79:5156:1)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?9e79:4939:1)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?9e79:4897:1)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?9e79:4489:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?9e79:5037:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?0a2b:167:1)
```

How do I fix this?

If these errors are showing because `let imageUpload: Ref<ImageUpload>` does not have any default values set, how do I set the defaults?

And is there a better way of doing this so I don't have to declare `let imageUpload: Ref<ImageUpload>` at the top level?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by initalizing the non-optional `imageUpload` properties.

So delete this line:

```
let imageUpload: Ref<ImageUpload>;
```

And replace it with this:

```
let imageUpload = ref<ImageUpload>({
  isCanceled: false,
  isRunning: false,
  isPaused: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isError: false,
});
```